# How to change ajax url when used in a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can `url` be changed from `/devices/cars` to `/devices/trucks`?  I chan change autocomplete's source, but as a matter of principle, would rather not duplicate the callback.

```
$(function(){
    $("#autofield" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/devices/cars",
                data: {term:request.term, type:'all', fields:['id','name']},
                success: function(json) {
                    var data=[];
                    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                        data.push({id:json[i].id,label:json[i].name});
                    }
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).parent().find("input[name='itemId']").val(ui.item.id);
        }
    });

    $("#changeUrl").click(function() {
        //Change url from /devices/cars to /devices/trucks
        $("#autofield" ).val('').autocomplete( "option", "source", function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/devices/trucks",
                data: {term:request.term, type:'all', fields:['id','name']},
                success: function(json) {
                    var data=[];
                    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                        data.push({id:json[i].id,label:json[i].name});
                    }
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        } );
    });
});
```

Comment: you would like to change it on runtime?

Comment: @ArupRakshit  Change it after page load.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I see is to just create a variable that will be your url, unless I'm misunderstanding your question.

```
var dynamicUrl = "/devices/cars";

$("#changeUrl").click(function() {
    dynamicUrl.val(dynamicUrl.val() == '/devices/cars' ? '/devices/trucks' : '/devices/cars');
});

$.ajax({
...
    url: dynamicUrl,
...
```

Comment: I don't think `dynamicUrl` can be referenced this way.

Comment: @user1032531Why not? I just tested an ajax call and you can most definitely pass a variable to the url parameter instead of a string.

Comment: Yes, with the ajax part you could, but autocomplete's closure is causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to change the URL based on an array index.
This will enable you to use as many URL as you wish.

Notice that you have to destroy the previous instance and re-instanciate it with the new URL.

```
$(function(){

    var ajaxURLs = ["/devices/cars","/devices/trucks", "/devices/planes", "/devices/boats" ];

    var usedURL = 0;  // The array index.

    function autoCompleteInit(){
      $("#autofield" ).autocomplete({
          source: function( request, response ) {
              $.ajax({
                  dataType: "json",
                  url: ajaxURLs[usedURL],
                  data: {term:request.term, type:'all', fields:['id','name']},
                  success: function(json) {
                      var data=[];
                      for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                          data.push({id:json[i].id,label:json[i].name});
                      }
                      response(data);
                  }
              });
          },
          minLength: 2,
          select: function( event, ui ) {
              $(this).parent().find("input[name='itemId']").val(ui.item.id);
          }
      });
    }

    // On load init
    autoCompleteInit();

    // Change handler
    $("#changeUrl").click(function() {
        //Change URL to the next URL in array

        usedURL++;

        // Back to first URL if cycled throught all URL
        if(usedURL > ajaxURLs.length-1 ){
          usedURL = 0;
        }

        // Destroy previous autocomplete instance ans re-initialise it with the new URL.
        $("#autofield" ).autocomplete("destroy");
        autoCompleteInit();
    });
});
```

Comment: I guess I can just reapply each time, but seems like it should be possible to be more precise.

Comment: Instead of destroying previous autocomplete instance ans re-initialise it with the new URL, just changing the URL.  Maybe just not possible.

Comment: The best way is to try... I admit I didn't tested... But I'm quite sure it has to be re-instanciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function containing the Ajax call and pass the url (or the prefix) as an argument.
Like
`getDevices(url)`